# How to write callback function for getting the collection object in nodejs.Here is java script function i wrote for getting collection object

Tags: node.js

```
function get_db_connection(database_name,collection_name){
    var collection;
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/'+database_name, function(err, db) {
        if(!err) { 
            collection=db.collection(collection_name);
            console.log(collection);
        } else { 
            console.log(err);
        }  
    });
    return collection;
}
```

i am simply confused with how to pass parameter to callback..will be better if someone post help link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return from an asynchronous function, you need to use a callback.

```
function get_db_connection(database_name, collection_name, callback) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + database_name, function(err, db) {
        if(err) { 
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, db.collection(collection_name));
    });
}
```

You'd then use it like

```
get_db_connection(database_name, collection_name, function(error, collection) {
    //do something with collection
});
```

Comment: Please don't swallow errors, the correct thing to do is `return callback(err)` to propagate it until it reaches someone who knows how to actually handle it. If I called this function and there was an error how do you suppose I would report it to the user? Actually my callback would never even be called and the user would get a infinite loading page until the request times out or something.

Comment: @Esailija It was just an example. I would've expected the OP to implement correct error handling procedures and not to just copy and paste my code.

Comment: My point wasn't that your code doesn't do error handling, the point was that your code didn't propagate callback, that's essentially the same as having syntax error except much harder to detect.